# Safari address bar disappears all the time

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, safari

something that annoys me, the address bar on Safari keeps on disappearing when I quit and re-open Safari, on default. In fact, when I open a new tab it does the same. Not sure why it does it, i have tried customising toolbar and adding address bar there again.

Comment: Is it *only* the address bar (location) part of the toolbar, or the whole toolbar that disappears?

Comment: The whole toolbar that disappears mate

Comment: If the address bar keep disappearing, then follow this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/60434/5730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Safari over the past several months. The toolbar (which includes address bar, google search, buttons, etc) was hidden almost every time I relaunched Safari even though the toolbar is visible before quitting (I manually select show toolbar in the View menu). I tried resetting the default in the customize toolbar option. I trashed the prefs. I even trashed Safari and its library then reinstalled a fresh copy. The toolbar still remained hidden most of the time unless I manually request it to be shown with the "View.." menu item (and then would be hidden on next relaunch).

Now, finally!, I think I found the solution. With the toolbar visible (select show toolbar in View menu), hold the right button over the toolbar area so a contextual menu is shown.  Select  "Keep visible" in that menu.

Looks like this is a semi-bug in Safari, folks. If the user selects the toolbar to be visible by default using the customize menu, then the toolbar should be kept visible. For some of us, that isn't happening unless we also select the "Keep Visible" in the contextual menu for the toolbar.

EDIT (next day): Sorry for the above.  Still having a problem with a disappearing toolbar. Unless I'm missing a hidden button somewhere, looks like this might be a full-blown Safari flaw that affects only some people. Maybe a toolbar-less auto window that popped up in the past permanently changed Safari's internals that users can't alter back again?

Comment: true im testing it out now will let you know if it re-appears. maybe a complette deletion of safari and its plugins?

Answer (score 2):

How do you make it show? If it is hidden then using `Command-L` will only temporarily show it until you press Return.

What if you hit `Command-|` ([*pipe*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_%28character%29), so probably `Command-Shift-\`) or use menu View, Show Toolbar, and then restart Safari right away?

Comment: No that seemed to work, just command shift \

Comment: Hiya, no its not working sorry been out for a while. Basically, command-shift-\ brings up address bar, but this setting keeps on resetting when you restart safari.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I have seen this when a web site overrides, and hides the toolbar.  Safari seems to save the window settings of the last window closed, when you quit it.

So, try this.

- Open Safari
- Edit --> Show Toolbar
- Quit Safari
- Restart Safari

And let us know what happens.

Comment: yeah i dont know it seems to work randomly, sometimes it does show automatically sometimes doesnt. Strange!